# генерация html с помощью шаблонов

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, шаблоны, nextjs

Есть ли в `next.js` аналог шаблонов `v-for` из `vuejs`?

Во vuejs я могу сделать так:

```
<div
       v-for="b in menu_sections"
       :key="b.id"
>
...
</div>
```

Можно ли аналогичное сделать в reactjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и в Реакте. Метод `map` к массиву https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html